# Regex to match any three words at max or no word btw 2 words

Tags: python, regex

Regex to match any three words (at max) between 'NATURAL' and 'FLAVOR'.

For example, from the following strings:

1. I have NATURAL SMOKE FLAVOR, and other elements.
2. I have NATURAL LEMON AND SALT FLAVOR, and other elements.
3. Noor has NATURAL FLAVOR in her ingredients.

I want to match:

1. "NATURAL SMOKE FLAVOR"
2. "NATURAL LEMON AND SALT FLAVOR".
3. "NATURAL FLAVOR"

I'll appreciate the help.
PS. I am working on python.

Comment: please add your attempted regex

Comment: *"I'll appreciate the help."*: ok, but then tell us what problem you encountered to do just that?

Comment: It's unclear if you expect any punctuation or other non-word sequences inside two words. 
And also, why do not you need regex, not just python split, index?

Comment: I am trying the following regex:
'NATURAL.*?(?=FLAVOR)FLAVOR'
This regex is working fine but the issue is it matches everything between NATURAL and FALVOR. So if I have the following string:
"NATURAL SALT, TOMATTOES, LEMON, ART FLAVOR". The above regex will match everything which I don't want. I just want to remove the words like NATURAL FLAVOR, NATURAL LEMON FLAVOR etc.

Comment: Maybe then `\bNATURAL(?:\s+[A-Z]+){0,3}\s+FLAVOR\b`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Use the following regex if the words are separated by spaces only `NATURAL(?: [A-Z]+){0,3} FLAVOR`
- Use this regex if the words are separated by spaces and optionally commas `NATURAL(?: [A-Z]+,?){0,3} FLAVOR`

Comment: The words are space separated. Thanks it resolves the issue